# Handling pagination with Blogger Api

Tags: blogger

I understand the documentation regarding the nextPageToken and retrieving subsequent pages.

My question-- what is the best practice to implement a way to go to the PREVIOUS page?

Comment: You can store the nextPageToken for the previous pages (as suggested in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545635/pagination-in-google-app-enginesearch-api ) Otherwise, you can store the `published` property of the last post of a page, and then using the query parameter `endDate` ,use it to go to the next page (Vice a versa, you can use the `published` parameter of the first post of a page and then using the query parameter `startDate` , go to the previous page)